# Using web-browser control with angularjs

Tags: javascript, angularjs, webbrowser-control

Trying to do below:

(a) Embedded a web browser control inside a winform.

(b) Pass a string data from winform control to webbrowser via Invoking a method in JS.

This JS method further calls the angularJS controller.  Call is successful. However, the controller which is used in view does not gets updated.

Snippet below:

Invoking side C# winform snippet:

```
string testString = "testing";
webBrowser2.Document.InvokeScript("InvokeJSPassingTestString", new object[] { testString });
```

HTML Side.

```
<html ng-app="ManagerApp">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <title></title>
    <script src="Scripts/angular.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        var angularApp = angular.module('ManagerApp', []);
        angularApp.controller('ManagerCtrl', ['$scope', function ($scope) {
            $scope.customParams = {};
            $scope.updateCustomRequest = function (data) {
                $scope.customParams.value = data;
                alert("$scope.customParams.value :" + $scope.customParams.value);
            };
        }]);

        function InvokeJSPassingTestString(data) {
            var dom_el = document.querySelector('[ng-controller="ManagerCtrl"]')
            var ng_el = angular.element(dom_el);
            var ng_el_scope = ng_el.scope();
            var test = ng_el_scope.updateCustomRequest(data);
        }
    </script>
</head>
<body ng-controller="ManagerCtrl">
    Passed parameter from winform to JS to angularJs is as below:
    {{ customParams.value }}
</body>
</>
```

In above snippet - I get the alert but the view {{ customParams.value }} does not gets updated.

Any inputs appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You code is running outside the angularjs digest cycle, so you need to start a new digest cycle after changing data

```
$scope.updateCustomRequest = function (data) {
    $scope.$apply(function () {
        $scope.customParams.value = data;
        alert("$scope.customParams.value :" + $scope.customParams.value);
    });    
};
```

[How to update bindings](http://jimhoskins.com/2012/12/17/angularjs-and-apply.html#how_do_we_update_bindings)